# which lane to turn into?

Tags: engine, motorcycle, motors

I have a question for left/right turn. Please excuse me if it is already been asked.

When you are turning left into a 2-lane road from a 2-lane road, we should stick to the lane which we are in. Correct? i,e, if we started with left lane we should end up into left lane after the turn.

1. But what if we start from a single lane which is ending into 2 lane road. Which lane to choose right or left lane after taking left turn?
2. What if there are 2 lanes to start with and more than 2 lanes to turn left into. Lets say 3.
   If we are at left most lane at first ...which one we should turn into out of the 3 lanes.
   If we are at right most lane at first ...which one we should turn into out of the 3 lanes.
3. What if there are 2 lanes to start with but only 1 lane to turn into? Who gets the preference if there are simultaneously 2 car turning into this single lane road?

Do the answers change if I have to take right turn instead of left?

Please help. 
Thanx.

Comment: unfortunately driving techniques like this are off topic.  You should consult your local driving laws as they will likely be able to give you the correct information.

Comment: Unfortunately, this question can only be answered with "you should do what the local laws require."

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid the only answer I can offer on a Global forum is "Whatever the local traffic regulations stipulate".